# How to send a file from the browser to a remote IPFS gateway

Tags: ipfs

I have an input field that's calling a _getFile function

```
<input type="file" class="file" on-change="_getFile"/>
```

the get file

```
_getFile(event) {
  this.loading = true;
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  let reader = new window.FileReader()
  reader.onloadend = () => this._saveToIpfs(reader)
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
 }
}
```

once we have an array buffer we then call...

```
_saveToIpfs(data){

}
```

It is this that I need help with, I want to send the selected file to 'https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add' or 'https://ipfs.io/api/v0/add ' how to do? is it an xhr post? I expect to get an IPFS hash back

The below simple form seems to upload the file and then get disconnected with the error ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

```
<form action="https://ipfs.io/api/v0/add/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

I aso tried a classic XHR

```
_getFile(event) {
const file = event.target.files[0];
var data = new FormData();
data.append('path', event.target.files[0]);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4){
        console.log(request.response)
    }
};
request.open('POST', 'https://ipfs.io/api/v0/add');
request.send(data);
}
```

with again ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the official [js-ipfs-api](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api) library. Then you can use the [`ipfs.files.add`](https://github.com/ipfs/interface-ipfs-core/blob/master/SPEC/FILES.md#filesadd) function to post your file, since you already have it in an array buffer. If that doesnt work, the js-ipfs-api has a built in Buffer object you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the [Gateway API](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/writeable-http-gateways/210) instead of the Node API. Just POST a file to it, you'll get a hash back.

For an example, see how [IPFessay does it](https://gitlab.com/stavros/IPFessay/blob/master/ipfessay/index.html).